# How to get data from controller to view using ajax request - asp.net mvc 4

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to get data from controller to view using ajax but not successfull. Following is my code this is working fine but not getting data. Please help and correct me if i missed something in my code.

Following is my code.

```
@model MvcAppLearn.Models.Student


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>This is tile</title>
</head>

<body>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "popup", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "myform" }))
    {
        <p>
            Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
            <button id="model-opener">Open dialog</button>
        </p>
        <div id="dialog-model" title="This is title">
            <p>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(item => item.FirstName, new { id = "ffirst" })<br />
                @Html.TextBoxFor(item => item.LastName, new { id = "llast" })<br />
            </p>
        </div>

    }


</body>
</html>

@section script
{

    <script>

        $(function () {

            $("#dialog-model").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 300,
                width: 340,
                model: true,
                show: {
                    effect: "shake",
                    duration: 100
                },

            });

            $("#model-opener").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var txtFirstName = $('#ffirst');
                var txtLastName = $('#llast');
                var txtSearch = $('#SearchString');

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/popup/Index',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {
                        StudentId: txtSearch.val()
                    },
                    success: function (data) {

                        txtFirstName.val(data.FirstName); //HERE IS THE PROBLEM IN GETTING VALUE
                        txtLastName.val(data.LastName);   //HERE IS THE PROBLEM IN GETTING VALUE

                        $("#dialog-model").dialog("open");
                    },

                    error: function () {
                        alert("Oh noes");
                    }
                });

            });

        });


    </script>

}
```

Below is my controller

```
public ActionResult Index(int? StudentId)
    {
        if (StudentId == null)
        {
            StudentId = 2;
            return View();
        }
        using (var db = new StdContext())
        {
            Student std = new Student();
            std = db.Students.Where(m => m.StudentId == StudentId).Single();
            return View(std);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not returning data, you're returning a view:

```
return View(std);
```

If you just want to return the *data* of the `Student` object to be consumed by JavaScript code then you probably just want to return it as JSON data:

```
return Json(std);
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer, but how to get data as json in ajax? can you please share any example or code?,

Comment: @user3004110: Well, the first example that comes to mind is the code in your question.  The `data` object in the success handler should be a JSON-serialized `Student` object.

Comment: you need a jsonResult method in the controller

Comment: @JackM: Returning `JsonResult` satisfies the `ActionResult` return type.

Comment: Iam new to mvc and learning ajax and json also. plz provide me an example or plz correct my code example. Really appreciate your help....

Comment: @user3004110: If you make the change I suggest in my answer, what happens?  I'm not going to build your application for you.  The reason your JavaScript code wasn't able to access data elements was because you weren't returning structured data, you were returning an HTML view.  If you return `Json(std)` that will return structured data.  Your JavaScript code should then be able to use that data *exactly as you are trying to*.  If something still isn't working, please describe the problem specifically.

Comment: Thanks this solved my issue but arise another little problem which is: I want to send two type of models one is return json(std) and another is return View(model). How can i achieve this???, thanks

Comment: @user3004110: You can't return two different responses simultaneously. It's either JSON or a view, not both. For either one you can combine the models into a composite model, but the response type itself has to be the same. A different response type would have to come from a separate request.